# Why SBT project cannot use log in Intelj IDEA 2017.1.4?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, log4j

Today, I build a simple project in **Intelj IDEA 2017.1.4**, then I add the following dependencies to `build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies += "log4j" % "log4j" % "1.2.17"

libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.13"

libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-log4j12" % "1.7.13" % "test"
```

[image]

I know the above declarations correspond to the following jars:

```
log4j-1.2.17.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.13.jar
```

Then I build a `trait` called `LogSupport.scala` in my project.

```
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator
import org.slf4j.{Logger, LoggerFactory}

trait LogSupport {
  protected val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)
  PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch("./conf/log4j.properties")
}
```

Lastly, I use this trait in `MyApp.scala`

```
object MyApp extends App with LogSupport {
  logger.info("program begins to start...")

  logger.info("program has completed the work...")

}
```

When I run `MyApp.scala` in IDEA, the console prints related warning:

[image]

However, when I move three jars to `lib` folder, it works well.

[image]

[image]

================================

Could someone tell me why? Thanks very much.

#### Use logback

I add `logback` to `build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3" % Test
```

Then I notice that IDEA **cannot** load `slf4j-api.jar`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to the order the classloader is loading jars and the place where it first find a `log4j.properties` file.

I would remove them from the lib directory, and pass your `log4j.properties` file location explicitly:

[image: Loading log4j properties]

Another option is to make sure IntelliJ views your "resources" folder as a source folder. Go to: File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Select your module -> Click on "Source" on the navigation panel -> Add the "resources" folder as a source folder:

[image: Sources]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tested your first method, then I discovered that it cannot work.

Comment: I remove the code `PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch("./conf/log4j.properties")` in `LogSupport.scala` and add `-Dlog4j.configuration="\conf\log4j.properties"` to VM options. Lastly, I run MyApp. I noticed that the console shows `SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".`

Comment: Another method I used is `logback`. I add `libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3" % Test` to `build.sbt`. Please see this [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ts2il.jpg). So I guess is it a bug of IDEA? Beacuse IDEA cannot find the jar of `slf4j-api.jar`

Comment: @xyz Did you refresh build.sbt? Also, did you try the second approach?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the second approach. Please see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieL5G.png)